# laravel 5.4: before submitting data from form popup comments model and then send them all

Tags: php, laravel

I have a form with 2 fields `price` and `order_id` then the `submit` button all I need to do is

- when user click on submit button bootstrap model popup and ask him for comments
- User write the comments and clicks on submit button
- Takes these values `price`, `order_id`, and the `comments` and send them to the controller and do whatever there.

Here is how my form looks in my blade

```
{!! Form::open(['route'=>['inline.update.price', $order->id], 'method'=>'patch']) !!}
{!! Form::text('price', $order->price, ['style'=>'width:100px']) !!}
{!! Form::hidden('orderListId', $orderList->id) !!}
<input type="submit" class="btn fa-input updatePriceButton" value="&#xf01b;">
{!! Form::close() !!}
```

I think of make it with session like

```
<a href="" class="btn fa-input updatePriceButton" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#supplierComments">
<i class="fa fa-arrow-circle-up"></i>
{{ Session::put(['orderId' => $order->id]) }}
</a>
```

Comment: i think you need to add tags bootstrap, html

Comment: You can use the jquery here. On clicking on the submit btn under popup add the value to the hidden element that you will need to create the above form. and final submit all data

Comment: @J.Doe yes I understand, adding the bootstrap tags and model but when I click submit the form it will takes the `price` and `order_id` and whatever there and send it to controller, understood but before that I need to popup a new bootstrap model and take the comments first and then send them all to the controller.

Comment: @sachinkumar ،،You can use the jquery here،، yes can you please show me example here

Comment: You can do the same with javascript, while click on the submit button on poup then you can append the comment box value in the current form and submit them.

Comment: @DsRaj can you please show an example.

Comment: @DsRaj you mean to show the price update again on the bs model? no I need the user to write for example the new price and when he click submit show the popup with comments only and then when he submit take all to the controller

Comment: No, When user click the submit after adding the comment, Submit the Price and comment with javascript

Comment: @DsRaj please show an example here please

Comment: Check this: [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/vc_dinesh/pbwev9sf/) after submit check the console.

Comment: Yes this is what I want exactly thanks pro and please added as an answer to be accepted here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per discussion in comment:

When you submit the first form open the model,

Get input from User for comment and then submit the whole form via ajax
Check this:

```js
$(document).on('click', '#submit-btn', function() {
    var comment = $("#comment").val();
 var data = $('#mainForm').serialize()+ "&comment="+comment;
    console.log(data);
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Example</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<div class="container">
  <form method="POST" action="/" accept-charset="UTF-8" id="mainForm">
    <input name="_method" type="hidden" value="PATCH"><input name="_token" type="hidden" value="YSEKhNUe8Zh6Q9Xju9nfGBeB2QD1Q7XFS6E4Ssoy">
    <input style="width:100px" name="price" type="text" value="">
    <input name="orderListId" type="hidden" value="">
  </form>
  <a href="" class="btn fa-input updatePriceButton" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#supplierComments">
  <i class="fa fa-arrow-circle-up"></i>
  Submit
  </a>
  <!-- Trigger the modal with a button -->
  <!-- Modal -->
  <div class="modal fade" id="supplierComments" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-sm">
    
      <!-- Modal content-->
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
          <h4 class="modal-title">Modal Header</h4>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
          Comment
          <input type="text" id="comment">
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal" id="submit-btn">Submit</button>
        </div>
      </div>
      
    </div>
  </div>
  
</div>

</body>
</html>
```